Need WPF GridSplitter that can automatically resize to zero
I want to make a custom GridSplitter that combines a regular splitter behaviour plus a feature - when the splitter resizes automatically one of the areas to zero.
So normal usage is:
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" Name="A"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" Name="B"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  
  <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"... />

initially - both columns A and B have same size = 50% of available width.
User can drag the splitter to change their widths.
Now I want user to be able to double click on the splitter (or any other way to initiate the action) - and the column A resized to 0 and B to 100%, if acted again - then A to 100% and B to 0.
Obviously I can do it in the parent by setting column widths in code behind. But I want to reuse this functionality in other parts and make it as simple to use as possible.

The best way to achieve this is to create your own GridSplitter or add a behavior to it using an attached property.
Here I provide a custom implementation of GridSplitter by inheriting of it.
To move the splitter I use a GridSplitterAutomationPeer:
public class MyGridSplitter : GridSplitter
{
    private readonly ITransformProvider _automationPeer;

    public MyGridSplitter()
    {
        _automationPeer = new GridSplitterAutomationPeer(this);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);

        var prtp = GetPositionRelativeToParent();
        if (prtp.X is 0)
        {
            _automationPeer.Move(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue);
        }
        else
        {
            _automationPeer.Move(-double.MaxValue, -double.MaxValue);
        }
    }

    private Point GetPositionRelativeToParent()
    {
        return TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as UIElement);
    }
}

You use it like this:
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="LEFT" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <local:MyGridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="RIGHT" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>

Note: only the left-right behavior is tested.
Working code available here.

yes that what i was looking for but wasnt sure how to access what I am resizing from inside the custom control

I find GridSplitterAutomationPeer by looking on the usage of the private method GridSplitter.MoveSplitter using ReSharper decompiler and usage tools. There is no other ref of it in SO
